# What are the best practices on catching COM-exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, com

Could you, please, tell me how to handle COM exceptions in C# in a right way?
For example, I am using `DirectorySearcher` and getting the `COMException: The server is not operational`. How should I handle this exception? I can write a handler for `COMException`, but how I identify particular exception type? Should I examine exception message or `HRESULT` for it?

Comment: The ComException.ErrorCode property is the same as the HResult property.  But is public so you can access it without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must look for the `HRESULT`, this **is** the **[errorcode of the Exception Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysft67da.aspx)**, and therefore the only way to really know what is going on. You can decypher the `HRESULT` with **[this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/07/21/441391.aspx)** and **[this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eldar/archive/2007/04/03/a-lot-of-hresult-codes.aspx)** article.

**Example:**

```
try
{
    //Your code
}
catch(COMException ex)
{
    int error = ex.ErrorCode;

    //Conditions and error handling
}
```

Basically the `HRESULT` is a 32 bit integer where the two most significant bits describe what sort of message it is (succes, info, warning, error). The other 30 bits are used to describe the rest of the message.